# Disambiguate the [django-q] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [django-q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-q) tag is used to refer to two things:

- The [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q), used for filtering, and creating WHERE clauses which contain OR or AND operators.
- The [Django Q library](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is "a native Django task queue, scheduler and worker application using Python multiprocessing." It's useful for doing asynchronous work.

The tag guidance says this:

> A Q() object encapsulates a SQL expression in a Python object that can be used in database-related operations.

Officially, this tag is only for the first use. But in practice, it's a different story. I looked at the last 50 uses of this tag, classifying each into either database use or the Django Q library use. In 48% of cases, this tag is used for the Django Q library. The remaining 52% of the time, it's used to mean the Q object.

With that in mind, here's my suggestion:

- Remove the [django-q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-q) tag from all questions which mean it in the database sense. This does not need to be a dedicated tag any more than the `filter()` operator needs a dedicated tag. The [django-queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-queryset) tag covers the same topic.
- Change the tag guidance to "Django Q is a native Django task queue, scheduler and worker application using Python multiprocessing. Not to be used for Django's Q() object."

Comment: The Q object is part of the django models. It shouldn't have its own tag for a single class.